# Appsee heatmap on ios

Tags: ios, heatmap, appsee

Is Appsee (or any other analytics platform) allowed to create heatmaps on ios?
I can't find any documentation that says if Apple allows the recording of heatmaps or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since heatmaps are a result of data aggregated from multiple sources (i.e. devices), they are usually created and computed on server, not on device. This is probably why you can't find documentation regarding recording of heatmaps.